# SQL Word Formation to a sentence

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I looking for a way in sql to combine entries to match a specific combination. 
E.g of Table:

Entries:

```
Username (nvarchar(255)) 
WordEntry (nvarchar(255))
```

Output, entries and count where persons words "My Name is Earl"

```
Username   Count 
TestUser   3
TestUser2  1
```

Comment: What does the data in your table look like to get that result?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you are looking for the substring in the wordentry field.  If that is not what you want, please clarify the question.  One of the following should work:

```
select username, count(*)
from t
where wordentry = 'My Name is Earl'
group by username
```

This assumes you want an exact match.

Or, perhaps you are just looking for that substring in wordentry:

```
select username, count(*)
from t
where wordentry like '%My Name is Earl%'
group by username
```

Comment: no, all the word entries have to form a particular sentence and if there is more than one combinations it must be able to find it. Each entry is separate and together it forms a particular sentence.

Comment: @AmarnauthPersaud . . . you need to explain the question much, much better.  What you want is not clear.